# A thread that runs without stopping

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, daemon

Is it possible in java to create a thread that will always work in the background? The problem is that the application instance sometimes crashes with an OutOfMemoryException. Therefore, several instances are launched in parallel. Each instance does some work: it saves something to the database at the request of the user. And the stream, which should work constantly, will look into the database and somehow process the information from it.

Most likely, the sheduler will not work, since the thread must be running constantly and wait for a signal to start working.

Comment: `instance sometimes crashes with an OutOfMemoryException. Therefore, several instances are launched in parallel` that's quite a ducktape solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set a infinite loop and break it. (Java threads)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854812/how-to-set-a-infinite-loop-and-break-it-java-threads)

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Yes I know. But unfortunately I'm not a team leader and I can’t influence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you investigate and resolve the OutOfMemoryException because it better to avoid these cases. You can instanziate a thread that wait for a request, execute a request and then return to wait for another request. The implementation is like this for thread:

```java
/** Squares integers. */
public class Squarer {

    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> in;
    private final BlockingQueue<SquareResult> out;

    public Squarer(BlockingQueue<Integer> requests,
                   BlockingQueue<SquareResult> replies) {
        this.in = requests;
        this.out = replies;
    }
    public void start() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        // block until a request arrives
                        int x = in.take();
                        // compute the answer and send it back
                        int y = x * x;
                        out.put(new SquareResult(x, y));
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

And for the caller method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BlockingQueue<Integer> requests = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    BlockingQueue<SquareResult> replies = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    Squarer squarer = new Squarer(requests, replies);
    squarer.start();

    try {
        // make a request
        requests.put(42);
        // ... maybe do something concurrently ...
        // read the reply
        System.out.println(replies.take());
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To more information, you can start to read the post that I found [here](https://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa14/classes/20-queues-locks/message-passing/) to provide you the example.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need an infinitely running thread with some control.

I found this answer to be the simplest and it does what you need.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2854890/11226302